# How to arrange columns in different projects in PWA

Tags: project-server, pwa

I imported 2 project in PWA through project professional.In one project i have 5 columns. Another project have 7 columns.Custom columna i created in task summary view.But 7 columns are displaying in both projects in .if i hide also it is hiding from both two projects.I f i enable also it is enabling two projects.How to solve?I am using project server 2016